# How to fix 'HTTP-415' error, during POST request in REST web service using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, http-status-code-415

I am a beginner in Spring Boot and learning my way through.

How to fix 'HTTP-415' error, during POST request in REST web service using Spring Boot as below? I have tried `@RequestMapping` annotation, `@RequestParam`. `@RequestParam` gives some other error 401. However, 415 is consistent with `@RequestMapping` and `@PostMapping`.

Issue with `@PostMapping` request.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-12-31T18:29:36.727+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 
    'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported\r\n\tat 
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
    AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.
    readWithMessageConverters
    (AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:224)\r\n\tat 
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.
     RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.
     readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)
     \r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.
     annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.
     resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
     \r\n\tat...................
```

While placing following request:

[image: Post Request]

StudentController.java

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    :
    :

    @PostMapping("/students/{studentId}/courses")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> registerStudentForCourse(
            @PathVariable String studentId,
            @RequestBody Course newCourse) {
        Course course = studentService.addCourse(studentId, newCourse);

        if (course == null)
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().
                path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(course.getId()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

StudentService.java

```
@Component
public class StudentService {
    :
    :
    public Course addCourse(String studentId, Course course) {
        Student student = retrieveStudent(studentId);

        if (student == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String randomId = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
        course.setId(randomId);

        student.getCourses().put(course.getId(), course);

        return course;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot</groupId>
 <artifactId>student-services</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>student-services</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
 <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to set the "Content-Type" header to application/json ?

Comment: You use Xml type content , change it by json

Comment: As Ken Chan said, try to put content type header in controller and client side. HTTP 415 happens when  from front end data sent with ambiguous or wrong content type to backend.

Comment: Thanks all, issue is fixed by adding content header as you all suggested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is Fixed by adding content header as application/json

[image]

Answer (score 11):

it's clearly in postman you are sending information as form-urlencoded but in your controller, you are expecting a request body (e. json), so you need either change `@RequestBody` to `@ModleAtrributes` or send you information with header `Content-type: application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Your controller needs no changes. Add consumes and produces to `@RequestMapping` of your `FeignClient`. It has worked out even without `@Headers`:

```
@FeignClient(name = "myFeignClient", url = "${com.example.url}", configuration = FeignConfiguration.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "feign-my", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
//@Headers({ACCEPT + ": " + APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, CONTENT_TYPE + ": " + APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public interface MyFeignClient extends MyController {}
```